# Ubuntu started randomly segfaulting after force power off due to usage of RAM

Tags: shutdown, segmentation-fault

So I accidentally ran a script which used up all of the RAM on my ubuntu system, and I had to force it to power off. When I rebooted the system, programs would randomly segfault, even though I changed nothing and they had never done this before. How would I fix my server so that these programs start working again? I've already tried reinstalling them via APT, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Had to force it to power off?   Why didn't you command the kernel to safely shutdown (ie. SysRq key + commands allow you to bypass any running programs/X/GUI etc and directly command the kernel?).  You should never need to use the power-off button (except where kernel panic is involved; as then you can't direct the kernel to do anything as it's already dead).  Given you powered your system off (unclean shutdown), did you `fsck` your system & check for *logical* errors?

Comment: @guiverc I tried to fsck my system using the recommended method but I can't tell if it did anything, as bootup takes the same time with or without the "fsck check". Furthermore, the laptop running the server doesn't have a SysRq key, only a print screen key.

Comment: By a miracle another restart seems to have fixed all of the problems, so I'll be happy that it's not permanently dead.

Comment: Many *modern* keyboards don't have SysRq marked on the keys (as a majority of users never used the key, not having it marked made the device appear *cleaner*, eg. 2019-2021 dell laptops don't), but if you know where the key is - it still works (though some models require an extra *Fn* key to be pressed to get the SysRq key effect; but how the key is achieved is machine specific, esp. *firmware* on the machine).